# Discuss the existence and uniqueness of solution of $u_x+5u_y=0$ with $u=g$ on $5x=y+1.$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Consider the initial value problem $$u_x+5u_y=0 \text{ with} \ u=g \text{ on the line } 5x=y+1.$$
>
> Discuss the existence and uniqueness of solution.

I think we cannot apply the non-characteristic condition(i.e. the existence and uniqueness theorem of first order pde) here because it vanishes. How can I show it ?

Please someone give some hints.

Thank you..

Comment: Your characteristics will necessarily be parallel to your initial data, they will give you no new information

Comment: Do you know what happens when the initial data is prescribed along a characteristic?